# Rails relationship undefined column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, model-associations

I have Users and Absences

```
class User
  has_many :absences
end

class Absence 
  belongs_to :student, foreign_key: "student_id", class_name: "User"
end
```

and my Absence migration has

```
t.integer :student_id, index: true, null: false
```

For some reason, I can say

```
Absence.first.student
```

but when I say

```
Absence.first.student.absences
```

I get

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column
>   absences.user_id does not exist) LINE 1: SELECT  "absences".* FROM
>   "absences" WHERE "absences"."user_...
>                                                      ^ : SELECT  "absences".* FROM "absences" WHERE "absences"."user_id" = $1 LIMIT $2

Obviously, I haven't set up sth right as it is looking for user_id instead of student_id but I have no idea why this happens... Thank you for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are getting this error because you didn't specify custom foreign key in has_many relation. Following code will solve your problem.

```
class User
  has_many :absences, foreign_key: "student_id"
end

class Absence 
  belongs_to :student, foreign_key: "student_id", class_name: "User"
end
```

Comment: I didn't know I should do that... Thanks :)